# Rails: What column type to use for saving uploaded images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first Rails project. I'm a bit stumped on how image files should be saved in the database, since they take up a lot of space. My site is going to be one where people upload a lot of images. In my migration for creating the pictures table, would I save the image file name as a string? Also does anyone have hints on where to save the images (assets, public, etc)?

Sorry, I'm just a noob looking for a little guidance.

Comment: pictures in database? really?

Comment: `t.column :picture, :binary, :limit => 10.megabyte`

Comment: would there be a better location to store these images instead of putting them in the database? I was thinking putting just the filename and storing the actual files in another folder, but I'm not sure where they would go

Comment: Put them on the filesystem, either locally, or in the cloud. Essentially all the file upload gems can streamline this process for you, although it's trivial to implement on your own. As far as *where*, wherever makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider storing your images on Amazon's S3 (or a similar alternative) instead of the database. You can use gems like [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to help you with uploading to a remote storage server.

However, if you really do want to store the binary image data in the database, then you probably want to use 'blob' as the column datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave). Just create a string column and mount an uploader on it.

Blobs should only be used in special cases!

Answer (score 0):

You save the images as files on a storage system on a server or the cloud.  Then, you create a record in your table with the path to it.

Do not store an images byte for byte\BOLB.

Comment: Why not use blob type?